# Реализовать клик по элементу в Selenium.Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Нужно нажать по span с тексом Галерея. Пробовал кликнуть через xpath, используя расширение в гугле, он его просто не находит, попробовал сделать так:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span')[0]: element.click()
```

но в этом случае он тоже не может нажать по ней. Без ошибок.

Помогите пожалуйста. Код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Барон Авто: Загрузка фото</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link href="/bt501/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/UP_photos/css/style.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
   <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css"
    />
    <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/UP_photos/css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/UP_photos/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/UP_photos/css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css"></noscript>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/UP_photos/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="sticky-top">
    <table class="table"><tbody>
        <tr><td><nav style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: url(&#34;data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.5 0L1 1.5 3.5 4 1 6.5 2.5 8l4-4-4-4z' fill='currentColor'/%3E%3C/svg%3E&#34;);" aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page"><strong><a href='/' class="link-dark">ETK.CLUB:ID</a></strong></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"></li>
  </ol>
</nav></td>
<td align="right"><h3>bmwgarage</h3></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
</div>

    <div class="container">
    <form id="fileupload" action="./server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="id_item" type="hidden"  class="form-control" value="" maxlength="10">
    <input name="num_or" type="hidden"  class="form-control" value="" maxlength="15">
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
                <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                                <div class="fileupload-progress">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        <span class="btn btn-outline-dark fileinput-button">
                    <i class="bi bi-camera"></i>
                    <span>Камера</span>
                    <input type="file" capture="environment" name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" multiple>
                    <!-- capture="camera" -->
                </span>
                <span class="btn btn-outline-dark fileinput-button">
                    <i class="bi bi-images"></i>
                    <span>Галерея</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" multiple>
                    <!-- capture="camera" -->
                </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input')   -    input не является css селектором

Comment: Да, я исправил, понял это, но и в этом случае не работает

Comment: на что исправили? есть  какая то ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так, для меня это сработало:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("file:///root/Desktop/2.html")

actions = ActionChains(driver)    
for _ in range(3):
    actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
actions.perform()
 
time.sleep(5)   
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Если это то что надо, отметь решение галочкой.